# What is "!!" in C?

Tags: c, gcc, boolean, boolean-expression

I have encountered the following snippet:

```
pt->aa[!!(ts->flags & MASK)] = -val;
```

1. What does `!!` (double exclamation marks/ exclamation points/ two NOT operators) stand for in c?
2. Doesn't `(!!NULL) == NULL`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307281/c-operator-is-a-two-not

Comment: example: In my code "[**Decimal to Binary: Size independent: First Method**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104208/convert-integer-to-binary-and-store-it-in-an-integer-array-of-specified-sizec/14314522#14314522)" I have used `!!` to convert a `int` into `0` or `1` bit

Comment: Also please note that this code is bad. Problem 1: using a bool as array index. Problem 2: the weird !! syntax, which only confuses the reader (as we can tell from this question). Problem 3: calculating array index with a needless complex expression, it should have been moved to a line of its own. All of these things point to the same thing: I suspect that we have a programmer who think they are terribly smart, but in reality have much to learn about proper program design and code maintenance.

Comment: Speaking of the _possible duplicate_ nomination, keep in mind that C and C++ are two _different_ languages. As a result I believe it is reasonable to have two independent questions with independent answers. Even if semantics are similar today, future standards may change this state.

Comment: Jan is correct, the answer to the linked duplicate is not correct for C.

Comment: @Jan, this question is tagged as [tag:c], and the related question is tagged as [tag:c]. if the tags are incorrect, they should be updated.

Comment: @JackAidley, if the accepted answer is not correct, then someone looking for an answer should place a bounty on the existing question, not ask a duplicate.

Comment: @zzzzBov: both answers are correct. They are not duplicates. C and C++ handle this differently, the duplicate pointed to a correctly answered C++ question; this is a correctly answered C question. And, now, I see the question is correctly not marked as a duplicate. All is good in the hood.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Actually I see this has been marked as a duplicate of more than one; the one it is _now_ suggested as a duplicate of, is a c question - also answered correctly - it had been tagged as a duplicate of a question asking the same thing for C++. Confusion reigns!

Comment: Mind you, Jan's answer is better than the one to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307281/c-operator-is-a-two-not

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`!` is negation. So `!!` is negation of negation. What is important is the fact that the result will be an `int`.

- `!!x` if `x == 0` is `!!0`, that is `!1`, that is `0`.
- `!!x` if `x != 0` is `!!(!0)`, that is `!!1`, that is `!0`, that is `1`.

`!!` is used commonly if you want to convert any non-zero value to 1 while being certain that 0 remains a 0.

And indeed, `!!NULL == NULL`, since `!!NULL == !!0` and `!!0 == !1` and finally `!1 == 0`.

Consequently, in the short piece of code you cited the array subscript will be either `0` if the value of the expression in parenthesis is `NULL`, and `1` otherwise.

Comment: The resulting value is either `0` or `1` of type `int`.

Comment: `(!!NULL) == NULL` is true if `NULL` is `0`. If `NULL` is, say, `((void*)0)`, you might get a pointer-to-integer comparison warning. The whole point of using `!!` is to convert from "truey" and "falsy" expression results to integers.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, @pmg, thanks, I've added information about the value of the expression being an `int`.

Comment: !!NULL should never be a warning regardless of the type of NULL. !ptr is normal usage.

Comment: @SandyLee: Not quite. `!!false` is `0`, and `!!true` is `1`.

Comment: I have heard `!!` referred to as the _normalise_ operator.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya Also, note that while `!!0` is `0` and `!!1` is `1`, `!!2` is also `1`, as is `!!3`, `!!4`, `!!5`... etc. It'll convert any value to a 0 or a 1.

Comment: The bit about NULL is incorrect...even aside from the `(void*)` warning, it's possible (but incredibly rare) to have a computer in which the value of a null pointer is non-zero, and so the C standard allows NULL to be any value, it could be `(void*)INT_MAX` for example, which would make your statement false. I'm not sure what percentage of C code would fail to run correctly on such a system, but there's no need to encourage people to make that non-standard assumption and write more non-standard code.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock: Most cases that describe the behavior of `NULL` are talking about the behavior of pointer expressions that happen to equal null, rather than merely null pointer constants; and applying `!!` to a pointer expression will yield a value that cannot be compared with any other pointer expression that isn't a null pointer constant.

Comment: @supercat Are you saying that the standard specifies the behavior of negation of pointers such that the negation of a non-null pointer is always NULL, and the negation of NULL is always some non-NULL pointer, so long as the compiler knows the value is a pointer? I was assuming that boolean negation of a pointer would proceed by reinterpreting the bytes of the pointer as an integer value of the same width, following the 'everything is a memory word' philosophy of pre-typing versions of C, that resulted in so many types that silently degrade to other types in modern C.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock: The negation operator always yields a value of type `int` which is either one or zero.  A literal zero, used in contexts requiring a pointer, will be converted to a null pointer, and because of this some implementations define `NULL` as a synonym for `0`.  On those implementations, `!!NULL == NULL` would be true, but `!!NULL` would not be a pointer, but rather an integer value of zero.

Comment: @supercat But the question is whether `!!NULL == NULL` is true in C, as stated in this answer, not whether there exist some implementations in which this example of undefined behavior just so happens to be well-defined.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock: `NULL` is a macro whose definition is supplied by the implementation if `<stddef.h>` is included.  Whether the exact expression `!!NULL==NULL` would be true or whether it would be regarded as a constraint violation would depend upon how the implementation chooses to define that macro, but I can't think of any situation where that exact expression would be useful.

Comment: @supercat Of course it's not useful, it's meaningless garbage that shouldn't be in this answer.

Answer (score 29):

It is commonly (ab)used to convert any value into the `int`s 0 or 1 by repeated application of the boolean not operator, `!`.

For instance: `!56` is 0, since 56 is "true" when viewed as a boolean. This means that `!!56` is 1, since `!0` is 1.

Comment: You say  "abused", but this is a common idiom. What do you suggest as a concise alternative?

Comment: @PCLuddite Well I did say "(ab)used", hinting that the abuse accusation is a bit tongue in cheek". I would probably recommend `pt->aa[(ts->flags & MASK) != 0]` since I think that is much more clear and explicit.

Comment: it's quirky, but it's not one of the worst abuses of C, and definitely not one of the worst abuses of C++. That language was just built for code abuse.

Answer (score 7):

`!E` is the same as `E == 0` so `!!E` is the same as `(E == 0) == 0`. `!!` is used to normalize booleans values.

Answer (score 4):

It converts a number into a canonical Boolean.

And note that in this case it's critical to do so, since the result is being used to index an array.

Answer (score 4):

In C99 you can replace it by

```
#include <stdbool.h>


pt->aa[(bool)(ts->flags & MASK)] = -val;
```

Of course if your code is to be portable to C89 then you'd be better off doing the !! trick or

```
pt->aa[(ts->flags & MASK)!=0] = -val;
```

or

```
pt->aa[(ts->flags & MASK)?1:0] = -val;
```

The generated code will be certainly identical.

Answer (score 2):

1. `!!x` is just a `!(!x)`.
2. if `NULL` is defined as 0 then `!!NULL == !!0 == !(!0) == !(1) == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

!! is a decent way to quiet the compiler in certain situations such as assignment in a conditional with more than one expressions, e.g:

```
int _blah = 100;
int *blah;
if ( _blah > 100 && !!(blah = &_blah) ) {
// do stuff
}
```

I don't recommend this -- warnings are usually there to enforce good coding practice.