# Confused by use of double logical not (!!) operator

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I have some C++ code that makes extensive use of `!!`. I'm kinda baffled because as far as I know `!!` is not a operator on it's own but two `!` after each other. So that would mean that `!!foo` is the same as just `foo`.

Is there any place and or reason when `!!` actually makes sense? I was thinking about if it could perhaps have a bit wise meaning? So you first perform some bit wise operation on `foo` and then `!` on the result? But I don't seem to remember `!` being used as a bit wise operator and don't seem to find any reference telling me it is either. As far as I can tell `!` in only used as a logical operator and in that case

`!!foo == foo`

Comment: One can also write `x+++++y+1`, but it's a bad idea.

Comment: @GrahamBorland Now I am going to go over there and vote that as a duplicate of this.

Comment: You may also like to read this: [*what is !! in c?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751973/what-is-in-c?lq=1).

Comment: @msw no you cannot. modifying more than once between two sequence points is undefined behavior. `!!` is perfectly defined and corresponds to triggering safe bool conversion operators. Which is particularly useful for `optional`, `variant` or any smart pointer.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It is not as simple as double negation. For example, if you have `x == 5`, and then apply two ! operators (`!!x`), it will become 1 - so, it is used for normalizing boolean values in `{0, 1}` range.

Note that you can use zero as boolean false, and non-zero for boolean true, but you might need to normalize your result into a 0 or 1, and that is when `!!` is useful.

It is the same as `x != 0 ? 1 : 0`.

Also, **note that this will not be true** if `foo` is not in `{0, 1}` set:

`!!foo == foo`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int foo = 5;

        if(foo == !!foo)
        {
                cout << "foo == !!foo" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "foo != !!foo" << endl;
        }



        return 0;
}
```

Prints `foo != !!foo`.

Comment: what might be the possible use cases for this?

Comment: Say you have some place where a bool is stored as a 1 or a 0, in a bit or something. And the value you check against is 5 (which would count as true), you can basically turn that 5 into a 1.

Comment: bool x = !0; // true
bool x = !-15 // false
int i = x;
Check this out

Comment: A bit more formally, its result is `true`. Values of type `bool` are `true` and `false`. In arithmetic contexts they are converted to `1` and `0`, respectively.

Comment: I have used this technique on a compiler that complained when I implicitly cast an `int` to a `bool` (performance warning: value will be converted to 0 or 1).  My options are to do a C-style `bool` cast (which I consider to be a bad habit), do `0 != v` (the `?1:0` afterwards is redundant) which creates order of operations ambiguity forcing `()`ing (at least to make it clear what is happening), or `static_cast<bool>( v )` which is overly verbose.  `!!` casts a type that is implicitly convertible to `bool` to `bool` without warnings and as a unary (and hence tightly bound) operator.

Comment: There are some difference between !!cond and !!(cond) ?

Answer (score 9):

It can be used as shorthand to turn `foo` into a boolean expression. You might want to turn a non-boolean expression into true or false exclusively for some reason.

`foo = !!foo` is going to turn `foo` into `1` if it's non-zero, and leave it at `0` if it already is.

Answer (score 4):

if `foo != 0`, then `!!foo == 1`. It is basically a trick to convert to bool.

Comment: `1` isn't a `bool`. It's an `int`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I know, I'm referring to the actual value.

Answer (score 3):

If `foo` is not of type bool, then `!!foo` will be. So `!!foo` can be 1 or 0.

Comment: `0` and `1` are `int`s, not `bool`s. We're talking about C++ here; maybe you're confusing this with C?

Comment: You're right. I should have said true or false. :)

Answer (score 2):

This technique is used for an safe evaluation of an variable in an boolean context. If you have an normal conversation to bool (`operator bool()`) unrelated variables (with differnt types) can participate in boolean expressions in an unwanted way. A defintion of `operator!` which returns a negated boolean value is implemented. And its result has to be negated again. Simply have a look at the [Safe bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Safe_bool).