# When to use the double logical not (!!) in C?

Tags: c, logical-operators

What are some valid uses for negating twice in C? For example, something like:

```
if (!!my_cond) {

}
```

As I understand, the `!!` will guarantee that the `!!my_cond` will be 0 if `my_cond` is `false` and 1 otherwise. When would you ever *need* to use this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751973/what-is-in-c

Comment: I understand what it does, I'm just trying to figure out why people want to "convert a non-zero value to 1". I'm sure there are valid uses, I'm just asking what some of those cases are.

Comment: @BlackJack: Using it as an array index in a two-element array, a flag, or in a bit array, as in: `array[!!x]`, `flags |= !!x << 4`, `bits[pos/8] |= !!x << pos%8`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context that you are showing it, it is useless, since the value itself would evaluate to `0` or `1`.

It can be usefull in a context that would not do such a "Boolean" conversion, such as arithmetic or indexing

```
size_t zerovalues[2] = { 0, 0, };

for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    ++zerovalues[!!A[i]];
```

At the end you'd have the number of values 0 of `A` in `zerovalues[0]` and the number of those that aren't in `zerovalues[1]`

Answer (score 3):

It can be used  for turning something into a Boolean expression.

If `foo = !!foo` it gives `foo` 1 if it's not a zero, and leave it at 0 if it already is.

Your question is already answered here :
[Confused by use of double logical not (!!) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191446/confused-by-use-of-double-logical-not-operator)

Comment: I don't think that the link really gives an answer about possible use cases.

Answer (score 2):

The double-negative can be used top convert logical expressions to 0 or 1 so that they can be compared to other logical expressions.

```
int x = 63;
printf("Output: %d  %d  %d\n", x, !x, !!x);
```

**Output: 63  0  1**

This allows some logical boolean comparisons that would otherwise fail.

Comment: C has had a bool type since C99.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a *good* use case, but it's not inconceivable that you could run up against interfacing with code which uses this anti-pattern:

```
if (x == TRUE) ...
```

More generally, if you're implementing an API that is documented as specifially returning `0` on failure and `1` on success, this is perhaps the simplest way to sanitise the final return value.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that this is used to tell the compiler to treat the variable being tested as a bool type