# What does this arrow function JavaScript code mean?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand HomeAssistant frontend source code. I have found function definition that I dont uderstand well. I dont understand this syntax (model.entity is a string)...

```
export function createHasDataGetter(model) {
  return [
    ['restApiCache', model.entity],
    entityMap => !!entityMap,
  ];
}
```

It looks like smth like:

`return [[string, string], bool]`?

What is exacly teturn type of this function? Is this just bool? If yes, does it mean entityMap is string array?

Comment: If you know it's an arrow function already, what are you confused about? Seems like you already know it's a function and not a `bool`.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: `entityMap => !!entityMap` is equivalent to `function ( entityMap ) { return !! entityMap; }`

Comment: Ok, so what actually is createHasDataGetter returning? Is it bool? Returned by arrow function? Why return statement has 2 argumets (array of strings and function returning bool)

Answer (score 3):

See ["Truthy" on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that translates to `true` when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`).

`entityMap => !!entityMap` maps `entityMap` to a canonical boolean value, `true` or `false`. See also [What is "!!" in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751973/what-is-in-c).

If `entityMap` has a truthy value, then `!entityMap` is `false`, and `!!entityMap` is `true`.

If `entityMap` has a falsy value, then `!entityMap` is `true` and `!!entityMap` is `false`.