# usage of !!, __warned and __ret_warn_once as int in WARN_ON_ONCE macro definition

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel

I was going through the [WARN_ON_ONCE](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.14/include/asm-generic/bug.h#L132) macro definition. I have doubt regarding the following line, what is the use of `!!` before condition. If we remove `!!` then also same will be stored in `__ret_warn_once`.

```
int __ret_warn_once = !!(condition);
```

What will happen when compiler executing the following source line.

```
static bool __section(.data.unlikely) __warned;
```

Comment: Hint: think about what happens if `condition` has the value `7`.  I am sure there have been previous questions about the `!!` construct but unfortunately one can't search for it.

Comment: "what is the use of `!!` before condition." - Have you checked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751973/what-is-in-c? As for `__warned` variable, it is used for implement "ONCE" semantic: the warning message is printed only on the first condition's violation; all futher violations won't emit a message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev , yes understood, its to convert non-zero value to 1 and zero to 0. So final value will be either 0 or 1, which can be treated as boolean. Not sure why the result was stored in int variable(`__ret_warn_once`), if we think it for more portability then at [line 136](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.14/include/asm-generic/bug.h#L136) the logical `&&` was used with a bool variable(`__warned`). So we can declare `__ret_warn_once` also as bool.

Comment: So the real question is "why variable `__ret_warn_once` is declared as `int` instead of `bool`", am I right? If so, this is very unobvious interpretation of your question post. And citing the line with **declaration** of `__warned` variable is very unobvious way for ask about of **usage** that variable in the following expression. Please, edit you question post to the form, when it would contain an **actual** question. BTW, your current question post doesn't contain a question statement at all.

Comment: @Tsyvarev , My initial doubhts are about `!!` and `static bool __section(.data.unlikely) __warned;`. After referring the links shared in the above comments, understood that `!!` is to convert the values to either 1 or 0. I am trying to understand the WARN_ON_ONCE macro definition, so when I check the next lilne, which is if condition, I got the question why can't `__ret_warn_once` can be declared as bool.

Comment: Please, update([edit]) the question post with your **actual** question. Note, that question post should be understandable **without reading the comments**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, edited the question, initial doubt was on `!!` and `__warned`, but while understanding the `!!`, got doubt about usage of `__ret_warn_once` as int. updated the three points in the question. Any reason behind using `__ret_warn_once` as int?